# How to create a unique index between two columns for all rows in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a constraint or a check to make sure that `sourceLocationId` and `destinationLocationId` can never be the same.

I have source being unique, and destination being unique and also unique between source and destination. But this can still happen.

Same source and destination in two different rows

[image: 1]

Is there any way to do this where essentially `sourceLocationId` is completely unique throughout the two columns and the same for `destinationLocationId`?

Comment: Strange requirement. You can go somewhere and then never leave.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just mean a `CHECK` constraint to ensure the two column values are never the same for *one* row? That would make a lot more sense.

Comment: You could create an indexed view to “unpivot” sourceLocationId and destinationLocationId into one unique column. Another, second table with 2 fixed values is used to unpivot: `create view dbo.v
with schemabinding
as
select case when ant.colX = 'a' then t.SourceLocationId else t.DestinationLocationId end as locationid
from dbo.TurretMovement as t
join dbo.anothertable as ant on ant.colX in ('a','b');` and `create unique clustered index uclxv on dbo.v(locationid);` ‘a’,’b’ could be numbers, dates or any two rows/values in a table which will not change.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather strange requirement, as it means that once a value has appeared as *either* a `SourceLocationId` *or* `DestinationLocationId` it cannot appear again. Normally you only want to ensure that pairs of them cannot duplicate, and that the two columns cannot be the same on the same row.

Be that as it may: you cannot do this in SQL on a single table. A primary or unique constraint can only be on a single column, or on *combinations* of columns, not *any of two* columns.

You need to normalize out your data into separate rows

```sql
CREATE TABLE TurretLocation (
    LocationId int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TurretId int NOT NULL REFERENCES Turret (TurretId),
    IsDestination bit NOT NULL
);
```

To get your original table, simply group by `TurretId`

```sql
SELECT
  TurretId,
  SourceLocationId      = MIN(CASE WHEN IsDestination = 0 THEN LocationId END),
  DestinationLocationId = MIN(CASE WHEN IsDestination = 1 THEN LocationId END)
FROM TurretLocation;
```